# Table-per-hierarchy and inheritance implementation issue

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, table-per-hierarchy

I am migrating an old ASP application to a modern .NET version, to cut down on development times we are looking at the .NET 4.0 Entity Framework. However, we seem to have hit a brick wall in our development with this issue.

Given is a small part of our database:
A table OBJECT which contains a list of cars and their respective properties. We also have a table OBJECT_OPTIONS which contains, for a given car in OBJECT, a list of OPTIONS, ACCESSORIES and STANDARD EQUIPMENT. These three types all have the same fields and are therefor stored in the same table. The column ncopt_type is used to discriminate between the different lists. Possible values are: 'opt', 'acc' and 'sta'. The table OBJECT_OPTIONS links to OBJECT via ncopt_obj_id which represents a unique car (obj_id) in table OBJECT.

Our goal is to provide the OBJECT entity with 3 properties that link to the different OBJECT_OPTIONS lists: 
- property OPTIONS
- property ACCESSORIES
- property STANDARDEQUIPMENT

We've tried different tutorials and walkthroughs concerning the table-per-hierarchy via inheritance model but haven't succeeded in creating a buildable model.

Technically what we did was:

- Create entity OBJECT
- Create entity OBJECT_OPTIONS, make it abstract
- Add entities OPTION, ACCESSORY and STANDARD_EQUIP all using basetype OBJECT_OPTIONS
- Add conditions to all three tables on ncopt_type = '...'
- Add 3 navigational properties to OBJECT, all linking to one of the inherited entities: OPTIONS, ACCESSORIES and STANDAARD_EQUIPMENT

A bunch of errors shows up during this setup, but we end up with this one:

> Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 250, 286:EntityTypes NCO.Model.OPTION, NCO.Model.ACCESSOIRE, NCO.Model.STANDAARD_EQUIP are being mapped to the same rows in table OBJECT_OPTIES. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

There is a condition present on all three objects though.

I have found no solution to this problem and have spent way too much time on it already. We are currently using a workaround method but would love to get this fixed as this situation will present itself a few more times by the end of the project.

Any help appreciated, if you need more information, please drop me a comment or an email.

Comment: It would appear not.  I've got the same problem,...maybe it's just us two!

Comment: Could you attach an image of the relevant tables and of the relevant entities from the edmx? - It would help clarify what you are trying to do. Leave a comment here after editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced you can do this 100% from within the EF designer, but you can do it like this:

> 1. Create entity OBJECT (I've renamed this 'Vehicle' for the example)
> 2. Create entity OBJECT_OPTIONS, make it abstract
> 3. Add entities OPTION, ACCESSORY and STANDARD_EQUIP all using basetype
>      OBJECT_OPTIONS
> 4. Add conditions to all three tables on ncopt_type = '...'

Then add in the properties you want using a partial class for Vehicle:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Vehicle
{
    public IEnumerable<ACCESSORY> Accessories
    {
        get { return this.OBJECT_OPTIONS.OfType<ACCESSORY>(); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<OPTION> Options
    {
        get { return this.OBJECT_OPTIONS.OfType<OPTION>(); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<STANDARD_EQUIP> StandardEquipments
    {
        get { return this.OBJECT_OPTIONS.OfType<STANDARD_EQUIP>(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, we have abandoned this method after it took to long to figure out. We might pick it up again in a future release. When we do I will try your solution. For now it seems that your solution might work so I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.